# Template is compiled before the result is returenf from $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am trying to retrieve data from the server using $http, and correct data is being retrieved from the service, the data is -

```
[{
    "URL":"someimg.jpg",
    "TITLE":"Test Demo",
    "DATE_ADDED":"2014-02-08 00:46:00",
    "SUMMARY":"this is summary"
}]
```

the template that I wrote is as follows -

```
<article class="span8" ng-controller="allBlogs">
    <div ng-show="success">
      <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs.data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span3">
            <img ng-src="{{blog['URL']}}" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="span5" ng-repeat-end>
            <h4>{{blog.TITLE}}</h4>
            <p>{{blog.DATE_ADDED}}</p>
            <p>{{blog.SUMMARY}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div >
    </div>
  </article>
```

the controller for the above template is as follows -

```
pk.controller("allBlogs", function($scope, $http, BlogsHandler){
    $scope.success = false;
    (function(){
        BlogsHandler.getAllBlogs().success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.blogs = data.data;
        });
    })();
});
```

I am trying to set the success as true when the service returns data and thus the remaining part of the template should run. But this is not happening. Is it not that any change to $scope variable is being watched by the framework itself?

Help needed. I even tried with ng-switch with no effect.

Thanks

Comment: Seems this should be `<div ng-repeat="blog in blogs">`

Comment: Also this should be `<img ng-src="blog.URL" alt="" />`

Comment: When I use <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs">,I get "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. "

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in ng-src.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `data.data` to `$scope.blogs`, so you don't need to add `.data` before `blogs` again.

```
  $scope.blogs = data.data;
```

So, try this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs track by $index">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <img ng-src="{{blog.URL}}" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <h4>{{blog.TITLE}}</h4>
        <p>{{blog.DATE_ADDED}}</p>
        <p>{{blog.SUMMARY}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div >
```

Comment: When I use <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs">,I get "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. "

Comment: oh I see. Add 'track by $index' to become <ng-repeat="blog in blogs track by $index">. You have at least two same blog value in blogs, so you must use 'track by $index' to differentiate them

Comment: this is the only data that I have.. [{
    "URL":"someimg.jpg",
    "TITLE":"Test Demo",
    "DATE_ADDED":"2014-02-08 00:46:00",
    "SUMMARY":"this is summary"
}].. Moreover when I use track by $index I get n number of repetitions without any data. I am struggling with this since long.. When I use static data.. I get the desired result.

Comment: data format is json. The structure is somewhat like this - {data:[{},{}]}

Comment: if your data is json format, you need to parse it to javascript object. Try this: $scope.blogs = (JSON.parse(data)).data;

Comment: I am sorry, but its already an object. typeof data gives "object" and JSON.parse(data) gives an error.

Comment: I put your data to blogs directly, and it work fine. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/OqL8ZJRMvsJEZCjO1N5X?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for showing me the right path by asking me the data type. The problem was that typeof data.data gave string. JSON.stringify(data.data) gave the correct response. The service returned the object but the main content was in json. Thanks for your time :)